# Forwarding undeclared methods-calls to a delegate

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I need to **separate the visual part of a component from the functional part** of a component, so that I'm able to replace the visual one with a new one for another platform.

Declaring an instance variable _delegate with the delegate's interface isn't a problem. But how Do I **forward non-implemented method calls of the visual part to those of the delegate**.

What's the equivalent of PHP's _call()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your post I thought of two ways of visual separation from logic. But I'm not sure it is what you want.

One way is to use **Code Behind** for your visual classes:

> http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Code+Behind

The other way of separation in flex 4 (spark) is the use of **Skin** classes:

> http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html

Of course you can always use some **Framework** to help you **separate the View from the Model or Controller (MVC)**:

> http://mate.asfusion.com/
>
> http://www.robotlegs.org/
>
> http://puremvc.org/

They might help you implement a useful design pattern to achieve that separation. For example:

> http://blogs.adobe.com/tomsugden/2009/08/applying_the_presentation_mode.html

Hope this helps,

Blaze

Answer (score 0):

Simply attach as event handlers? You can construct your function on stack, visiting some data structure (maybe your visual hierarchy, or some DB schema), then attach the appropriate event handlers to components. I'd try to follow such schema. Maybe because 'data as code' it's very natural in Prolog, the language I prefer.